# Getting all key values from JavaScript object with output to table

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object that looks like this, is there any way to search through each key value without specifying the name?

```
[ '1AB': { a: 'AB',
    q: 0,
    t: 0,
    pb: 0,
    tb: 0,
    po: 0,
    to: 0,
    pn: 0,
    tn: 0,
    type1: 'mix' },
  '1AJ': { a: 'AJ',
    q: 0,
    t: 0,
    pb: 0,
    tb: 0,
    po: 0,
    to: 0,
    pn: 0,
    tn: 0,
    type1: 'mix' },
  '1AK': { a: 'AK',
    q: 0,
    t: 0,
    pb: 0,
    tb: 0,
    po: 0,
    to: 0,
    pn: 0,
    tn: 0,
    type1: 'mix' }
]
```

Here you see the object is made of several objects with name "1AB" and so on.  Actually there are 400 of these.

I'd like to read all 400 objects within this object and output to a table so it'd have 400 columnns by 13 rows and 5,200 cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## First of all, the code you posted has error

```js
[
  '1AB': { a: 'AB', q: 0, t: 0, pb: 0, tb: 0, po: 0, to: 0, pn: 0, tn: 0, type1: 'mix' },
  '1AJ': { a: 'AJ', q: 0, t: 0, pb: 0, tb: 0, po: 0, to: 0, pn: 0, tn: 0, type1: 'mix' },
  '1AK': { a: 'AK', q: 0, t: 0, pb: 0, tb: 0, po: 0, to: 0, pn: 0, tn: 0, type1: 'mix' },
]
```

You wrote code like this, which is wrong because elements of Array don't have keys.

It should have look like this:

```
{
  '1AB': { a: 'AB', q: 0, t: 0, pb: 0, tb: 0, po: 0, to: 0, pn: 0, tn: 0, type1: 'mix' },
  '1AJ': { a: 'AJ', q: 0, t: 0, pb: 0, tb: 0, po: 0, to: 0, pn: 0, tn: 0, type1: 'mix' },
  '1AK': { a: 'AK', q: 0, t: 0, pb: 0, tb: 0, po: 0, to: 0, pn: 0, tn: 0, type1: 'mix' },
}
```

## Solution

[**Object.entries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) will do thing that you want.

```js
const data = {
  '1AB': { a: 'AB', q: 0, t: 0, pb: 0, tb: 0, po: 0, to: 0, pn: 0, tn: 0, type1: 'mix' },
  '1AJ': { a: 'AJ', q: 0, t: 0, pb: 0, tb: 0, po: 0, to: 0, pn: 0, tn: 0, type1: 'mix' },
  '1AK': { a: 'AK', q: 0, t: 0, pb: 0, tb: 0, po: 0, to: 0, pn: 0, tn: 0, type1: 'mix' },
}

Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(`key is "${key}"`)
  console.log(`value of property "a" is "${value.a}"`)
});
```

console:

```
'key is "1AB"'
'value of property "a" is "AB"'
'key is "1AJ"'
'value of property "a" is "AJ"'
'key is "1AK"'
'value of property "a" is "AK"'
```

So, now you can make the object to be iterable. you can use any methods to make table

Comment: Thanks. It works.  And if I understand your first comment right then [ ] means array and { } is object.